# Can I reference the result of the equation in the previous line to send an additional line of text?

Tags: javascript, math, random, reference, discord

I'm super new to JS and currently working on a discord bot.
I'm looking for a way to reference the above result that is being generated (a number from 1-20),
and have a command send an additional message if the result happens to be exactly a 20.
Can anyone help me with this, any tips would be appreciated? Thanks.
Examples below.

**Current code:**

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'roll',
    description: "this is a roll command!",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} rolled a **D20** <:d20:790654162600853535> and got***${Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1}*** !`);

        }
    
    }
```

**Current Result**:
@User rolled a D20 and got 20!

**Alternate Current Result**: @User rolled a D20 and got 5!

**Wanted Result** : @User rolled a D20 and got 20! !

```
                   @User rolled a Critical!
```

**Alternate Wanted Result** : @User rolled a D20 and got 5! !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want to look into the past when you have the power of variables?

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'roll',
    description: "this is a roll command!",
    execute(message, args){
        let roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} rolled a **D20** <:d20:790654162600853535> and got***${roll}*** !`);
        if (roll === 20) message.channel.send('@User rolled a Critical!');
        }
    }
```